# Automatic release using gitlab-runner and docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, release, gitlab-ci-runner, autorelease

I am converting my project in gitlab to exe using docker and gitlab-runner. Then I decided that I should use broadcast since I needed to make a version of this exe file. I can do this manually in gitlab but I want to do this automatically with commands I added to my yml file. but I'm getting an error and I couldn't find a solution.

There were suggestions such as delete gitlab-runner, install it again, stop and start the service. I tried these but it didn't work and I still get the same error.

I have a yml file like this. It doesn’t give an error in any job here, it only gives an error in the last release-job job.

```
default:
  image: docker:24.0.7
  services:
    - docker:24.0.7-dind
  before_script:
    - docker info

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

stages:
  - build
  - release

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - if [ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" = "stable" ]; then
        TAG="stable";
      else
        TAG="";
      fi
    - docker buildx build -t my-docker-image --platform linux/arm64 . --build-arg TAG=$TAG
    - container_id=$(docker run -d -t my-docker-image)
    - mkdir -p dist
    - docker cp $container_id:/app/dist ./dist
    - ls dist
    - export LAST_VERSION=$(cat version.cfg | grep VERSION | cut -d'=' -f2)
    - export NEW_VERSION=$((LAST_VERSION + 1))
    - echo "VERSION=$NEW_VERSION" > version.cfg
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
      - version.cfg

release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG                  # Run this job when a tag is created manually
  script:
    - echo "Running the release job."
  release:
    tag_name: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    name: 'Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    description: 'Release created using the release-cli.'
```

The error is like this;

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpaaT.png)

I think if there was a problem with Docker, it wouldn’t work in previous versions either. Can anyone with knowledge help?

Comment: `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest` image has no docker command

Comment: Yes, what could be causing the problem?

Comment: The problem is caused that the image `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest` has no docker command inside it. Thus, you get `docker: not found`.

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know. Does this need to have a docker command in it? I don't think I should intervene in it.
I'm trying it from here: https://docs.gitlab.com/16.5/ee/user/project/releases/release_cicd_examples.html

Comment: If you want to run `before_script: - docker info` then yes, if you want to use docker client in `before_script`, then you have to have docker client installed inside the environment that you are using if you want it to succeed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed this, and the problem has been solved.